# AngularJS: Access factory from within decorator

Tags: angularjs, decorator

I am extending a third party directive using a decorator. I would like to access one of my factories within the decorator. How can I do this?

```
$provide.decorator( 'multiSelectDirective', function( $delegate ) {
    var directive = $delegate[0],
        link = directive.link;

    // wipe out the shitty template
    directive.template = '';

    // make with the new template!
    directive.templateUrl = 'app/partials/filters.template.html';

    // hook into the compile phase of the directive
    directive.compile = function( ) {

        // the function returned by compile is the new link function
        return function( $scope, el, attrs ) {

            // run the original link function.
            link.apply(this, arguments);

            $scope.filterClicked = function( buttonName, selection ) {
                handleFilterClick( buttonName, selection, JiraData, GreyGooseApi );             
            }

        }
    };

    return $delegate;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was able to inject the dependencies in the following way:

```
$provide.decorator( 'multiSelectDirective',
    [ '$delegate', 'JiraData', 'GreyGooseAPI',
    function( $delegate, JiraData, GreyGooseApi ) {
        var directive = $delegate[0],
            link = directive.link;

        // wipe out the shitty template
        directive.template = '';

        // make with the new template!
        directive.templateUrl = 'app/partials/filters.template.html';

        // hook into the compile phase of the directive
        directive.compile = function( ) {

            // the function returned by compile is the new link function
            return function( $scope, el, attrs ) {

                // run the original link function.
        link.apply(this, arguments);

        $scope.filterClicked = function( buttonName, selection ) {
            handleFilterClick( buttonName, selection, JiraData, GreyGooseApi );
        }

            }
        };

        return $delegate;
    }]);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access all the properties the factory exposes via `$delegate.someproperty` if its not exposed you cannot access the property.